# What is the benefit of using observable in Angular 5 http requests?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, rxjs5

I am confused about using httpclient in angular 5.I am new to angular and just following the official angular tutorial.I dont know much about observables,promise,pipe etc..Currently I am having a service for handling all the http methods.For post request I am using with pipe.Below is the method.

```
create(model: any,URI) :Observable<Object>{
    return this.http.post(API_URL+URI, model)
    .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('create', model))
    );
}



private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
        return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

        console.error("default"+error); // log to console instead
        var errors=error["error"];

        var type=errors.errors;

        this.log(`${operation} failed: ${JSON.stringify(errors.errors)}`);

        return of(result as T);
        };
    }

      private log(message: string) {
        this.messageService.add('DataService: ' + message);
      }
```

And inside the component I am calling this create method like this..

```
onSubmit() { 
        this.loading = true;
        this._dataService.create(this.model,companytype_url).subscribe(data => {
            console.log("inside component data type-company"+JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error=>{
            var error_data=JSON.stringify(error);
            console.log("inside component error type-company ->" + error_data)
        }
        );
        this.submitted = true;
        this.loading = false;
        this.companytypeForm.reset();
    }
```

Should I use subscribe in component?
I need a general http class to handle the all the api requests.It is a big application and there are a lot of components.Since I am new to Angular I am confused about the different ways of calling http methods.

Comment: @DeborahK Please check this one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I use subscribe in component?

Yes. If you don't subscribe, nothing will be sent to the server

> I need a general http class to handle the all the api requests

That's what HttpClient is. If your service is completely generic, it won't add anything to what HttpClient already provides. Use dedicated services, which actually provide a higher-level abstraction: have typed arguments, transform inputs necessary, use the appropriate URL, return typed objects, know how to transform the response, etc.

> Since I am new to Angular I am confused about the different ways of calling http methods.

That's why Angular provides... documentation. For example, this [HttpClient guide](https://angular.io/guide/http), and this [RxJS guide](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library). Read them.

Comment: Thank you ..I have one more doubt.
When an error happen, the catchError works, and the handleError is executed .

However, when I subscribe, and place another error handler function in the subscribe, the function never executed even if error occurred.
Whenever data received, the  console.log("inside component data type-company"+JSON.stringify(data)) will be executed, even though if an error occurs.

Comment: That's because your error handler in the service (which is, most of the time, useless), doesn't re-throw the error as it should. You haven't posted it, so...

Comment: useless in the sense means ...I should remove that error handler from the service ?

Comment: I have no idea, since you didn't post it, and you didn't tell why you added it either. So I have no idea of what it does, and of why you think it's useful.

Comment: Please check the edited question..I have added the handleError method.My intention is to handle all the errors in the service itself.I don't want to handle those errors in all my components..

Comment: I fail to see the point of such a handler: it makes the quite strong assumption that you will get back a JSON error response that contains a field error that contains a field errors, logs that in the console (which is useless: the end user will never open the console, and you can just see the error in the network panel if needed), and then it returns the model to the caller, tricking it into thinking that everything went fine, although it didn't. Remove that handler.

Comment: If you need a **useful** error handler (to display an actual generic error message to the user, for example), then use an HTTP interceptor, as explained in the documentation. In any case, if you choose to continue using such a handler, it should return `Observable.throw(error)`, to propagate the error to the caller. Note that the handler will be called whatever the error is (including, for example, not being able to send the request, in which case you certainly won't have a JSON response)

Comment: Thank you very much..It is working when I put the code Observable.throw(error) in the handler.I am using the interceptor also.I will try to handle the error through interceptor..